# Inserir 'variável' no SRC da imagem

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço isso?

Preciso que uma "Variavel" fique no SRC da tag img, e ela puxe as imagens.

```
$JQuery('<div class="bannersucesso" style=" text-align: center;"><img src="#"></div>').insertBefore('.header-container');
```

Naquele src="#" ali, precisa ficar isso:

```
{{widget type="banner/widget_banner" template="banner/banner.phtml" banner="confimacao"}}
```

Só que ele não puxa a imagem. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Que tipo de plataforma está usando? E por que dentro do atributo src não pode ficar somente o caminho da imagem?

Comment: É Magento, só que é um Magento bem modificado, da BizCommerce, e não pode ficar só a URL pôs aquele widget ali puxa 2 imagens no caso, pro PC e pro responsivo.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso

Primeiramente vc deve dar um ID para sua tag IMG.

Exemplo:

**Código:**

```
<img src="" id="minhaImagem">
```

Agora dentro de seu código javascript vc pode alterar dinamicamente o atributo SRC.

**Código:**

```
<script> 
document.getElementById("minhaImagem").src = [URL_DA_IMAGEM] 
</script>
```

Substitua **[URL_DA_IMAGEM]** pela variável com o caminho da imagem.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Michael, mas fica dando erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {